Docker logs inside docker container
Is there any way we can see logs of running container inside container. For example, if we are running Alpine container, can we see its logs in Alpine container while it is in interactive mode?
I looked into logging drivers but could not figure out.

This is a Docker-specific case of Can a process read its own stdout/stderr?  That involves some tricky low-level file-descriptor manipulation.  Why do you want this?  Can your program save whatever state it needs in variables?
